# Office 365 - Excel process under Outlook

Tags: office365

When I look into my Task Manager, I noticed that Outlook was listing a couple Excel processes under it. Is this normal behavior or something abnormal.

Below is what I see in Task Manager:

[image: Excel/Outlook Task Manager]

**Note**: I went to Task Manager to look at the processes, as all Office 365 applications at that time was frozen and wasn't responding.

Answer (score 0):

This (above) occurs if you have opened an Excel Spreadsheet from within Outlook. Once you regain control (you said Office was frozen), restart and you will see that Outlook stands alone in Task Manager.

So from the point of view of the above, it is normal and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the case when I try to preview a Excel workbook in Outlook. Outlook calls Excel to transform the worksheet into a preview page. So, an Excel processes will be included in Outlook.

[image]

I'm agree with John. It is normal and expected behavior.